# How can I output a field as link?

Tags: views, 8

I have a title field and some date fields in my view in the following order

1.title

2.from_date

3.to_date

Since the title is long, I have trimmed and it is a known bug that the links don't work after trimming.

So how can I add a link to the title so that when I click on it, gets redirected? Please help somebody.

Comment: If it is a node, you can add the nid field, hide it and override the title field like `<a href="node/[node:nid]">[title]</a>`

Comment: Thanks. I have find a solution myself. Added a filed 'NID' above title and made it invisible. Also set custom path to the /node/{{nid}}. And it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution for the problem. Follow the steps.

1. Add a field 'Path' above the 'Title' field.
2. Exclude 'Path' field from display.
3. Uncheck the link to content from 'Title'
4. In Title->Rewrite Results check output this field to custom link and set path as {{ path }}.

OR

1. Add a field 'ID' above the 'Title' field.
2. Exclude 'ID' field from display.
3. Uncheck the link to content from 'Title'
4. In Title->Rewrite Results check output this field to custom link and set path as /node/{{ nid }}.

It both works.

Comment: You should add `Path` as a field, and then use `{{ path }}` instead of `/node/{{ nid }}` as the latter will never use your node's alias.